# point browser to image and use jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

How can I manipulate image in browser with jquery when the image is retrieved with:

http://slideshopro.com/dunlap-hall-entry-tower/wp-content/uploads/sites/621/2014/06/DSC02599.jpg?imageOnly=true

I tried to put:

```
 if($_GET['imageOnly'] == true) {

?>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            console.log('image');
        }
    </script>    
<?php

}
```

in index.php and in functions, but I could not get it to run.

Comment: What do you mean by "manipulate image" ?

Comment: zoom, pan and resize

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what you are asking here, but if you are talking about manually manipulating the image, that will be tough to do with jQuery alone, especially if you want to do something with the manipulated image. You will need to work HTML5 Canvas.

I suggest you check out [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/), they created a powerful and simple Javascript HTML5 canvas library.